# Is there a difference between SELECT * and SELECT ALL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

Basically this. I wonder if someone would use `ALL` instead of `*`, since I'm building automatized `SELECT` queries. Currently, if someone wants to select everything, the query will just use `*`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: @PaulF:- the link you provide is ALL keyword in comparision, not in SELECT

Comment: It is the MySQL documentation for the SELECT command - I just thought the OP should have checked that as a starting point for understanding the ALL keyword.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SELECT ALL` means ALL rows, i.e including duplicate rows. (The opposite is `SELECT DISTINCT`, where duplicate rows are removed.) `ALL` is the default, and most people write just `SELECT` instead of `SELECT ALL`.

`SELECT *` means all columns.

**Note:** When it comes to e.g. `UNION` suddenly `DISTINCT` is the default. So just `UNION` means `UNION DISTINCT`, i.e. duplicate rows are removed. Here you have to specify `UNION ALL` to keep duplicate rows.

Comment: you have to use SELECT ALL with * as you use SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: So `ALL` is just the default? I must admit that i've never seen it.

Comment: Yes, ALL is default as in Order By Clause, ASC is default

Comment: Got it. So I'll just provide `ALL` as a parameter like I do with `DISTINCT`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh wait, so if `ALL` is the default, there's actually no reason to provide it as a parameter. I'll just keep the way it is then... thanks!

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Then `select all *` and `select *` are the same ?

Comment: Where is it useful at all? Is it the same `ALL` as in `UNION ALL` which doesn't remove duplicates as opposed to `UNION`?

Comment: @stack ---Yes..I feel so

Comment: `DISTINCT` (either in `SELECT` or `UNION`) takes extra effort and (usually) slows down the query.  For `UNION`, I recommend _always_ adding `ALL` or `DISTINCT` -- that way it is clear to the reader that you thought about the choice.  Without specifying, I wonder if the writer accidentally picked the slower option for no good reason.